# Unable to convert Number(1,0) to bool

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6

I am using Oracle Managed Data Access components 
Code First

Attempting to convert Int16 to Boolean
but always receive an exception

> 'The 'property name' property on 'class name' could not be set to
>   'System.Int16' value. You must set this property to a non-null value
>   of the 'System.Boolean'

If I have a boolean as a property within my POCO and use either SqlQuery of the DbSet or manually create a datareader I receive a cast exception

Interestingly if I use normal EF such as

```
var test = dbContext.Set<Person>().Where(c=> 1==1).ToList();
```

no exceptions are thrown and the expected property values are set.

A basic model

```
public class Person
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

The call ToList raises the exception

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var dbContext = new Context();
     var sql = "select 1 Id, cast(1 as Number(1,0)) Active from dual";
     var query = dbContext.Set<Person>().SqlQuery(sql);
     var list = query.ToList();
}
```

I've defined edmMappings (I don't think this matters) in my config file as follows:

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <edmMappings>
        <edmNumberMapping>

          <add NETType="bool" MinPrecision="1" MaxPrecision="1" DBType="Number" />
          <add NETType="byte" MinPrecision="2" MaxPrecision="3" DBType="Number" />
          <add NETType="int16" MinPrecision="4" MaxPrecision="5" DBType="Number" />
          <add NETType="int32" MinPrecision="6" MaxPrecision="10" DBType="Number" />
          <add NETType="int64" MinPrecision="11" MaxPrecision="19" DBType="Number" />
        </edmNumberMapping>
      </edmMappings>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

My ultimate goal is to avoid modifying my POCO

Comment: Not sure why you would expect automatic conversion from an integer to a bool? Either make the database colum a boolean,  or make the class property an integer.

Comment: My version of oracle doesn't support boolean, not sure that any version does

Answer (score 2):

May be you can declare your entity class as below to achieve what you need

```
public class Person
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int Active { get; set; }
   [NotMapped]
   public bool IsActive 
   {
       get { return Convert.ToBoolean(Active); }
       set { Active = Convert.ToInt32(value); }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My end goal is avoiding modifying the model, or at the very least modifying the signature of my classes.  
  
It's a shame that the managed provider for Oracle failed to realize this short coming.

Comment: Is it auto generated class? Is that the real reason why you want to avoid modifying the model?

Comment: My classes were created manually. I've decorated each class and properties with TableAttribute, ColumnAttribute respectively

Comment: I see. may be we could use TypeConverters to do the auto conversion while mapping without extra properties as state above. Too bad, EF doesn't support them.

Answer (score 1):

Because in oracle doesn't exist boolean you can do something like this in your class.

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active {
        get { return Convert.ToBoolean(activeNumeric); }
        set { this.activeNumeric = Convert.ToInt32(value); }
    }
    private int activeNumeric { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's an improvement

Comment: @user1555297 You think this will help?

Comment: My models are all decorated as follows    
     
`[Table("Persons")]    
public class Person  
{   
 [Key, Column("PERSON_ID")]     
public int Id{get;set;}     
[Column("ACTIVE")]     
public bool Active{get;set;}    
    
}   
`   
If I used the additional private field as you propose, it would break my   existing data models because calling SqlQuery is a one off scenario   and wouldn't be used often

Comment: You can declare with notmapped

Comment: I looked further into using a private field to get the job done. Although this runs it doesn't ever set the 'activeNumeric' field. The value is always false.

The query ran = "select 1 Id, cast(1 as Number(1,0)) activeNumeric from dual"